# SSH Config is ignored by git client

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I interact with two different git repositories, both of them are GitLab implementation.

Since I need to use different users (and e-mail) to access them, I created two ssh keys: let's say `id_rsa_1` and `id_rsa_2`. After that I wrote a `~/.ssh/config` file to specify when each id_rsa file should be used. config file is:

```
Host gitlab.host1.com-user1
    HostName gitlab.host1.com
    User user1
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_1

Host gitlab.host2.com-user2
    HostName gitlab.host2.com
    User user2
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_2
```

My problem is every time I use `git`, that `config` file aren't take into account. It is always looking for id_rsa file.

What is wrong in my config file?
Is `Host` just a personal identifier or is it take into account during `git` searching for keys?

Which user should I provide? "git" or my real user registered in each server?

What is really wrong in my `config` file?
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Host` entry is a pattern that is matched to what host you request when looking for keys.  Then, `HostName` is what host is actually logged into, and defaults to the value for `Host`.  So, you could say:

```
Host gitlab.host1.com
    User user1
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_1
```

You could also specify `gitlab.host1.com-user1` as the host when you call git, and it should work with your current config.

For more info, you can check `man ssh_config`.